# Event handler for multiple checkboxes using this.bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, checkbox, jsx

```
class Equipments extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    arrayLength = props.data.length;
    this.state = { isChecked: new Array(arrayLength).fill(false) };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this); 

}

onChange(id){
    console.log("id",id)
    var tempArray = this.state.isChecked;
    // console.log("temparrayBeforechange",tempArray[id])
    // tempArray[id] == true ? tempArray = false : tempArray = true;
    tempArray[id] = !tempArray[id];
    // console.log("temparrayAFTERchange",tempArray[id])

    this.setState({isChecked: tempArray});
}


render(){
    var label = this.state.isChecked ? console.log("TRUE") : console.log("FALSE");
    console.log(this.state.isChecked)
    return(
        <div>
            <h1> Equipments  </h1>
                <ul> {this.props.data.map(function(equipment){


                    return <span key={equipment.id}>
                        <form>
                            <label>
                                {console.log("id", equipment.id)}
                                <input
                                name="isChecked"
                                value={equipment}
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={this.state.isChecked[equipment.id]}
                                onChange={this.onChange.bind(equipment.id)}
                                />
                                <a href={'/equipment/' + equipment.id} > {equipment.name}</a>
                                {label}
                            </label>
                        </form>
                        </span>

                    },this)
                    }   
                </ul>               
        </div>
    )   
}
```

}

So we tried your edits, but now only the last checkbox works and it only toggles to true, not to false. The rest of the checkboxes aren't even showing they are being selected, but are hitting the console.

This is what the this.state.isChecked is printing:

```
[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, [object Object]: true]0: false1: false2: false3: false4: false5: false6: false7: false8: false9: false10: false11: false12: false13: false14: false[object Object]
```

It seems like the Object: True is being appended to the array rather than accessing the relevant value in the array.

Also, on the onChange when I print ID it prints this object, I'm kind of confused on how we're using this.

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, _dispatchInstances: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "change"…}
```

So I guess what I'm trying to figure out is, how do we pass the equipment.id into the onChange to access the correct value in the array to change it from true to false or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Ok first of all, you only have one state variable determining whether or not the checkboxes are ticked. When you check one, isChecked becomes true, which checks all the checkboxes on the next render. To fix this, I'd turn isChecked into an array of objects so you can access the corresponding bool in the array using equipment.id. For this example I'm going to assume equipment.id is an int and your list of ids starts at 0. Let's also assume equipment has three items in it.

```
class Equipments extends React.Component {

fillCheckedArray(input) {
    var tempArray = [];
    for (item in input) {
        tempArray.push(false);
    }
    return tempArray;
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // equipments = props.data;
    var tempArray = this.fillCheckedArray(equipment);
    this.setState({ isChecked: tempArray });
    console.log(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this); 

}

//We now pass a parameter to access the relevant value in the array
onChange(id){
    var tempArray = this.state.isChecked.slice();
    tempArray[id] = !tempArray[id];
    this.setState({isChecked: tempArray});
}

//Now each checkbox accesses its corresponding value in the array, and calls
//the onChange function using their ids as array indexes
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1> Equipments  </h1>
                <ul> {this.props.data.map(function(equipment, index){


                    return <span key={equipment.id}>
                        <form>
                            <label>
                                <input
                                name="isChecked"
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={this.state.isChecked[index]}
                                onChange={this.onChange.bind(index)}
                                />
                                <a href={'/equipment/' + equipment.id} > {equipment.name}</a>
                            </label>
                        </form>
                        </span>

                    },this)
                    }   
                </ul>               
        </div>
    )   
}
}
```

Hopefully that works. Time allowing, I'd create a function that fills the isChecked array on initialization regardless of how many items are in equipment, but that's up to you.

EDIT: Implemented the suggested changes and now autofilling the isChecked array. Try it now.

Comment: **Few suggestions**: 1. you need to create a copy of `state array`, by `this.state.a.slice()` then perform the other operation, because by direct assigning array to any var, var will get the reference of `array` and it will do all changes directly to original  `array`, And `state` values should be changed only by `setState` 2. Instead of using `equipment.id` you can use the `array index` :)

Comment: That slice() thing solves so many mysterious issues I have had in the past, thank you. Also, how would you go about accessing the index of the equipment array?

Comment: `this.props.data.map(function(equipment, index)`, now use this index in place of `equipment.id`.

Comment: Getting this error 
'Uncaught ReferenceError: fillCheckedArray is not defined at new Equipments'

Comment: Possible long shot, but try it it now. I've declared fillCheckedArray before your constructor now.

Comment: I'm dumb. It should be `var tempArray = this.fillCheckedArray(equipment);` Try it now.

Comment: Same error. I don't think the constructor knows what fillCheckedArray is

Answer (score 0):

```
class Equipments extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // equipments = props.data;
    // var tempArray = fillCheckedArray(equipment);
    arrayLength = props.data.length;
    this.state = { isChecked: new Array(arrayLength).fill(false) };

    console.log(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this); 

} 




//We now pass a parameter to access the relevant value in the array
onChange(id){
console.log("id",id)
    var tempArray = this.state.isChecked.slice();
    console.log("temparraybefore!", tempArray)
    tempArray[id] = !tempArray[id];
    console.log("temparray",tempArray)
    this.setState({isChecked: tempArray});
}

render(){
return(
    <div>
        <h1> Equipments  </h1>
            <ul> {this.props.data.map(function(equipment, index){


                return <span key={equipment.id}>
                    <form>
                        <label>
                            <input
                            name="isChecked"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={this.state.isChecked[equipment.id]}
                            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this,index)}
                            />
                            <a href={'/equipment/' + equipment.id} >     {equipment.name}</a>
                        </label>
                    </form>
                    </span>

                },this)
                }   
            </ul>               
    </div>
)   
}
}
```

You need to add "this" in the input when you bind the onChange.